# Using for loops to generate 3D plot

Tags: python, for-loop, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to do a 3D plot in python, E vs (Ma/Mb) vs T, where T depends on E as well as Ma and Mb. My code is similar to the following:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from datetime import datetime
import scipy
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FormatStrFormatter

n= 30
Elist = numpy.linspace(0.00000001 , 1 , n)
L0 = 30  
V0 = 0.13
Mblist = numpy.linspace(0.1, 10, n)
Malist = numpy.linspace(10, 0.1, n)
R_list = []
T_list = [] 
m_list = []

def function(E, Ma, Mb):
    Ka =  (complex((Ma * E) / 13.6057))**0.5
    Kb = (complex((Mb * (E - V0))/13.6057))**0.5

    x = 1j * Kb * L0
    y = 1j * Ka * L0

    P = numpy.matrix([[1 , 1] , [Ka/Ma , -Ka/Ma ]])
    R = numpy.matrix([[numpy.exp(x) , numpy.exp(-x) ] , [(Kb/Mb) * numpy.exp(x), (-Kb/Mb) * numpy.exp(-x)]])
    Q = numpy.matrix([[1 , 1] , [Kb/Mb , -Kb/Mb ]])
    a = numpy.linalg.inv(Q)
    S = numpy.matrix([[numpy.exp(y) , numpy.exp(-y)] , [(Ka/Ma) * numpy.exp(y) , (-Ka/Ma) * numpy.exp(-y)]])
    b = numpy.linalg.inv(S)

    M = b * R * a * P
    m1 = M[0,0]
    m2 = M[0,1]
    m3 = M[1,0]
    m4 = M[1,1]    

    r = -m3/m4
    R = (numpy.abs(r))**2
    t = m1 - (m2 * m3)/m4
    T = (numpy.abs(t))**2
    R_list.append(R)
    T_list.append(T)    
    m = Ma/Mb
    m_list.append(m)

    return R_list, T_list, m_list

for i in range(len(Elist)):
    E = Elist[i]
    for i in range(len(Malist)):
        Ma = Malist[i]
        Mb = Mblist[i]
        R_list, T_list, m_list = function(E, Ma, Mb)

fig = pyplot.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
X = Elist
Y = m_list
X, Y = numpy.meshgrid(X, Y)
Z = T_list
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1,
                   linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
ax.set_zlim(-1.01, 1.01)
ax.zaxis.set_major_locator(LinearLocator(10))
ax.zaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.02f'))


'''
for i in range(len(Evals)):
    E = Elist[i]
    Ma = 0.084
    Mb = 0.1
    R_list, T_list, m_list = values(E, Ma, Mb)

#2D graph of E vs T

pyplot.plot(Evals, T_list, color='green')
pyplot.xlabel('Energy, eV', fontsize = 20)
pyplot.ylabel('T', fontsize = 20)
pyplot.ylim(-0.01, 1.01)  
'''


'''
for i in range(len(Malist)):
    E = 0.5
    Ma = Malist[i]
    Mb = Mblist[i]
    Rlist, Tlist, m_list = values(E, Ma, Mb)

#2D graph m vs T

pyplot.plot(m_list, T_list)
pyplot.xlabel('Mratio', fontsize = 20)
pyplot.ylabel('T', fontsize = 20)
pyplot.xlim(0, 20)
'''

pyplot.show()
```

I want to see how T changes with m (m = Ma/Mb) for each E value but using my code I cannot plot this as the final arrays are of different lengths (E values are as many as len(Elist) whereas m and T are as many as len(Elist) * len(Malist)). I think an easy way around this would be to use a for loop to loop over the E values, effectively plotting m vs T n times. I cannot seem to get this to work though, any help or other suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: could you please change the code into something that can actually be run and verified otherwise it's hard to figure out what happens and what would be the best course of action to help you.

Comment: I have changed the code to one which runs and shows the relevant error message @MSeifert